# What happens to animals after they die according to Islam?

Tags: death, animals

I would like to know if there is any Islamic evidence on the fate of animals after they die.

Answer (score 4):

These verses of Surat At-Takwir are said to be about the Day of Judgement:

> إِذَا الشَّمْسُ كُوِّرَتْ
>
> When the sun is wrapped up [in darkness]
>
> وَإِذَا النُّجُومُ انكَدَرَتْ
>
> And when the stars fall, dispersing,
>
> وَإِذَا الْجِبَالُ سُيِّرَتْ
>
> And when the mountains are removed
>
> وَإِذَا الْعِشَارُ عُطِّلَتْ
>
> And when full-term she-camels are neglected
>
> **وَإِذَا الْوُحُوشُ حُشِرَتْ**
>
> **And when the wild beasts are gathered**
>
> [[At-Takwir: 1-5]](http://quran.com/81/1-5)

So based on the last verse above, it seems that at the Day of Judgement, animals (at least some of them) are going to be gathered as well as humans. However, it's not clear what happens to them after that. <sup>[Tafsir Al-Mizan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafsir_al-Mizan)</sup>

Another evidence on this claim is the following verse which states that all the creatures (including animals) are going to be gathered at the Day of Judgement after their death:

> وَمَا مِن دَابَّةٍ فِي الْأَرْضِ وَلَا طَائِرٍ يَطِيرُ بِجَنَاحَيْهِ
> إِلَّا أُمَمٌ أَمْثَالُكُم ۚ مَّا فَرَّطْنَا فِي الْكِتَابِ مِن شَيْءٍ
> ۚ ثُمَّ إِلَىٰ رَبِّهِمْ يُحْشَرُونَ
>
> And there is no creature on [or within] the earth or bird that flies
> with its wings except [that they are] communities like you. We have
> not neglected in the Register a thing. Then unto their Lord they will
> be gathered. [[Al-An'am: 38]](http://quran.com/6/38)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer would be more complete and informative if you included evidence from the Sunnah, though.

Answer (score 3):

Allah Almighty says:

> And there is no creature on [or within] the earth or bird that flies with its wings except [that they are] communities like you. We have not neglected in the Register a thing. Then unto their Lord they will be gathered.

(Surah Al-An'aam 6:38)

The Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings be upon him) said,

> The claimants would get their claims on the Day of Ressurection so much so that the hornless sheep would get its claim from the horned sheep

[Sahih Muslim](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/262520)

> Rights will be given to their due (on the day of Judgment), such that the hornless sheep would get its claim from the horned sheep

[Jami at-Tirmidhi](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/677250)

Answer (score -1):

There are many theories in Islam, I think "Allah" has created animals with soul. Look at the "Zoljinah" which is still waiting for the revenge of Hazrat IMAM HUSSAIN (A.S). Animals that were killed with brutality without any purpose will be gathered on Judgement Day and will be given a justice. On one hand we believe that HILAL animals will be used on PUL sirat, and we also say "They are HILAL and that's why they will help us". But they are also a animal as compared to DOG, but the difference is "HILAL" and "HARAM". If they will be used on PUL SIRAT then the question arises that where will they go after? There is nothing created without reason. Allah who creates for reason then how can ALLAH kill without their place/purpose. Look at the pet at home, your dog barks when he feels terror, it provides protection so that you may sleep quite, so is this was the only purpose of creation of DOG. If they are vanished when a dog died/killed, then why they were given a soul, if then, Why the DOG of 4 pious people who are still sleeping will go to heaven. DOG who respected them will go to heaven so why the pets in our homes, they do nothing, they live according to our life/instructions, will die without purpose. Islam has a vast religion which demolish brutality so the animals will be given a place known to ALLAH. But it is clear that they have a place because they breathe, they are alive, they eat and so they may have a life after death. Furthermore you can add according to your perception and knowledge. I lost my lovable pets so I feel pain when they died. If i can feel the pain of animal who cannot speak then how they have only one life.

Answer (score -2):

I believe there is a difference between 'soul' and 'ruh.' A quick search will produce some ayats from the Quran. Every living creature, including animals, has a ruh. Allah swt breathes a ruh into his creation, bringing it to life. It's like divine energy. Once the body fails, the ruh returns home to its creator. Animals are alive so they too have a ruh that returns to Allah swt. Remember, the Quran says all living things return to their lord.

Soul is defined in terms of nafs. A person's nafs will encourage him/her to do righteous things or evil things.

Another point to be noted is that Allah swt says in the Quran that everything in heaven and earth worships him, including the moon, the stars, the sun, the trees, the animals, and communities of men from among mankind.

Animals are innocent. They worship Allah swt as he has ordained them to do. Look around you and you'll witness animals going through horrific situations, sometimes at the hands of human. Now think about Allah swt's endless mercy. You think he won't grant these animals some kind of reward for having glorified him and lived facing many challenges?

The Quran is silent on EXACTLY what the fate is of animals after they die. But it's clear their ruh return to Allah swt, and since Allah swt is ever merciful and neglects nothing, HE probably grants them some kind of reward.

Sorry I can’t find the exact Qur’anic ayats, but you can definitely search for them.

Comment: Welcome to [islam.se]. So in your terms ruh could more correctly be interpreted as *spirit*? Your answer needs reference to back it's claim and that's what's highly encouraged here on this site.

Answer (score -3):

Only three creatures have a soul: human, jinn and angels. All others have life, but no soul. These creatures and everything else on earth is created for mankind. There will not be any judgement day for them.

Comment: nice to read , but references?

Comment: Judgement day can only be for creatures that have their own will. I am sure you can easily find references for it in Quran

Comment: @goto Judgement day can only be for creatures that have free will, perhaps true, but how does it imply that animals don't have soul?